# Relationship between objects - ConvNets

Tags: convolutional-neural-network

Is there some interesting work on modeling relationship between objects in images? This seems like a natural extension to object detection/segmentation, but I couldn't find anything well-cited.

I'm looking for something like the following: a convnet predicts objects in the image (e.g. 'person', 'house', 'dog'). Each objects is examined wrt to relationship to other objects, e.g. 'person' 'in front of the' 'house', 'dog', 'to the left of the' 'person'.

Here the network must understand at least three semantic objects, but also learn to connects them in some sense with additional relationship objects like 'in front of', 'next to', etc. These relationship objects should probably also be pre-defined, like the classes. I can imagine learning some sort of graph edges, but not sure.